# Adobe AIR: How to play local mp3 file?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, urlrequest

I'm testing Adobe AIR with flex, and I wanted to play a mp3 via an open file dialog, I did that :

```
import flash.filesystem.*;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.*;
import mx.core.SoundAsset;

public var loadedFile:File;
public var channel:SoundChannel;
public var song:SoundAsset;


private function loadFile():void {
 loadedFile = new File();
 loadedFile.browseForOpen("Open multimedia File");
 loadedFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected);
}

private function fileSelected(event:Event):void {
 song = new SoundAsset()
 song.load(URLRequest(loadedFile.url));
 channel = song.play();
}
```

But when I try to open a file, after the Open file dialog close, I get this error :

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "file:///C:/Users/Kedare/Music/05-Scene%20V%20~%20Prelude.mp3" to flash.net.URLRequest.
```

I can't find anything related to that on Google or another documentation, all the docs I find is related to play a sound using URL and not Local files :(

Any idea of what can be the problem ? What can I do ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
song.load(URLRequest(loadedFile.url));
```

to

```
song.load(new URLRequest(loadedFile.url));
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please hit that big checkmark next to my answer to mark it as the solution and close the question. :)